How can I butt new drywall to an existing wall without affecting its texture?
I am renovating a hallway that was previously covered in wood paneling. The new drywall butts up to an existing wall with textured plaster. How should the outside corner bead be done where the two walls meet? If I scrape down the old wall to attach corner, I won't be able to match the texture as it's old plaster. Is there some other way to do this?

Pics would be helpful.

The detail isn't clear. Normally a wall butting to another doesn't result in an outside corner that didn't already exist. Maybe you meant that it terminates at an outside corner. Please revise to clarify. Provide a sketch or photo if possible.

I added an image to demonstrate. There was no old bead at the corner. It was just wood paneling installed all the way to the end with an unfinished edge. I'm trying not to mess with the old plaster wall as it was hand textured and there's no way I can match it.

Without seeing the exact detail, you would want to install a J bead flush with the textured wall. Fill any gaps with a paintable flexible caulking.
